# Python: Pandas Dataframe Create Individual Horizontal Bar charts for Each Distinct Category In Dataframe

Tags: python, loops, bar-chart, categories

I have the following dataframe:

```
Mon Year    Ratio Value Category
Jan 2016    0.024454035 A
    2017    0.048216976 A
    2018    0.064599633 A
Feb 2016    0.039955399 A
    2017    0.038249422 A
    2018    0.040955116 A
Mar 2016    0.047335373 A
    2017    0.095655431 A
    2018    0.018486543 A
Jan 2016    0.014454035 B
    2017    0.018216976 B
    2018    0.064599633 B
Feb 2016    0.039955399 B
    2017    0.083824942 B
    2018    0.080955116 B
Mar 2016    0.047335373 B
    2017    0.035655431 B
    2018    0.078486543 B
Jan 2016    0.024454035 C
    2017    0.018216976 C
    2018    0.024599633 C
Feb 2016    0.039955399 C
    2017    0.023824942 C
    2018    0.080955116 C
Mar 2016    0.037335373 C
    2017    0.035655431 C
    2018    0.008486543 C
```

I want to create a bar chart in Python (one chart per distinct category).  So I would have three separate charts A, B, C.

I want the y-axis to show 'Mon' column and the three years associated with the month.  I want the horizontal axis (x-axis) to show the ratio value.

Below is a hypothetical sample of one of the charts I want to produce (numbers do not match my example provided):

[image]

Since I have three categories in my dataframe, I would have three of these charts.

I have scoured Google but couldn't find anything to help me get this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

category = df['Category'].unique().tolist()
colour = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)
for i, cat in enumerate(category,1):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, i)
    df.loc[df['Category'] == cat, 'Ratio'].plot(kind='barh', color=colour)
    plt.title('Category ' + cat)
plt.xlabel('Ratio')
plt.subplot_tool() # should allow you to adjust the subplot spacing
plt.show()
```

[image]